# When I run rake to update db, do I have to stop rails server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I have rake tasks to update my database and the task is triggered by an external hook. (svn hook).

The rake task is going to insert new records and update some columns of existing records. There is no db schema change.

I should also mention this is in production.

- Do I have to stop the server while the rake task is running?
- If I stop the server, how can I display a "updating" message when visitors are viewing the website?
- Do I have to restart the server after the rake task is done?

Comment: In development or production?

Comment: @Mischa In production.

Answer (score 1):

You should not need to restart the rails server for a rake:db:migrate rake:db:reset or rake:db:create.

Comment: Depends on the environment. I'm pretty sure that you have to restart in production.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I have to stop the server while the rake task is running?

It depends... If your migration breaks previous version of rails site (for example field renaming or table deleting), then it may be better to show some kind of "We are updating our Web site, please come back in two minutes" page or just shut down rails server.

Ask yourself, will your previous version of code work with new database schema? If yes, then you don't have to stop server or show "we are updating" page. If no, then you should consider stopping the server during migration.

> Do I have to restart the server after the rake task is done?

No, if you are just adding/deleting/changing some records in database tables.
And yes, if you are changing database schema.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding redirecting, if you decided not to restart the server and the migration \ seeding is taking a long time, then just change the

```
// config/routes.rb
root :to => 'controller#action'
```

to some new controller that will display the appropriate message (changing it will take effect immediately, with no need for restart)